# Split column in 2 clomuns using comma as seperator

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I have table `listings`:

```
location (Primary Key)

Chicago, USA
New York, USA
Paris, France
```

The format is strictly

```
City, Country
```

Same as:

```
<City><comma><single_space><Country>
```

I want 2 columns from `location` (using commas as a separator) as:

```
city      country

Chicago   USA
New York  USA
Paris     France
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for this:

```
select 
    location,
    substring_index(location, ', ', 1) city, 
    substring_index(location, ', ', -1) country
from listings
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b5164df4e38102958bfe7cfc361d84f)**:

```
location      | city     | country
:------------ | :------- | :------
Chicago, USA  | Chicago  | USA    
New York, USA | New York | USA    
Paris, France | Paris    | France
```

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update listings
set 
    city = substring_index(location, ', ', 1), 
    country = substring_index(location, ', ', -1)
```

Comment: Ok, I am trying it now

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I have to insert values in City and Country columns. My bad